# script for mysql + apache + php installation

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I can install MySQL or any package from the code below but I wish to install multiple packages, one by one, from a single script.

---

```
echo "Do you wish to install MySql?" 
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do 
case $yn in 
Yes ) yum -y install mysql; break;; 
No ) exit;; 
esac
done
```

---

1). If type `No` then it will go on to next level e.g.`Do you wish to install Apache`.

2). If type `Yes` it will install MySQL then ask for next packages e.g.`Do you wish to install Apache`.

Could someone help me writing this script?

I will explain to you. I want to create script for **MySQL + Apache + PHP** installation.
If **MySQL** is already installed in my machine, I don't want to install it, then it will ask for me Do you wish to install **Apache**? if I press 1 it install then it will ask for me Do you wish to install **PHP** then exit automatically.

Comment: in which language? Perl Bash script?

Comment: So what's your particular problem? You can execute multiple commands in a `case` statement, like: `Yes ) yum -y install mysql; yum -y install php; break;`.. Can you elaborate on what's not working?

Comment: It is best to just run the appropriate install scripts and not try to make just the one script. It is a one off event that requires various configurations and thinking about what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for your script snippet for Bourne shell would be:

```
echo "Do you wish to install MySql?" 
read yn
case "$yn" in 
    Yes)
        yum install mysql
        ;; 
    No) ;; 
esac
```

Comment: I want to setup script for Apache + MySQL + PHP. So how can I do? e.g. I installed Apache using script then it should ask me for Mysql installation then it should ask me for PHP (PHP I dont want to install so I will press No for exit. I hope you all understand my question. I want script not for single package, it for multiple packages.

Comment: I have created script as: #!/bin/bash

# Update System Packages#
yum -y update    
#Install Apache#
yum -y install httpd

#Install Mysql#
yum -y install mysql

#Install PHP#
yum -y install php First thing this script will not ask you want to install or not? second thing if remove -y it will ask for any packge do you want to installed or not and it is irritating to me.

Comment: @ImranKhan I don’t get it. On the one hand you are irritated because `yum` will ask you whether you want to install the package or not. But on the other hand, when you use `-y` to quiet it, you now look for a way to make it ask whether or not you want to install the package. It sounds like you have irreconciliable whishes.